# Issue with Sequelize seeding Dialect error

Tags: mysql, sequelize.js, seed, sequelize-cli, dialect

I'm trying to seed my database with an npm script.

```
  "scripts": {
    "devstart": "set NODE_ENV=development && sequelize db:seed:all && nodemon ./server.js"
  }
```

I keep getting an error saying that I have to explicitly define the dialect in my config. This is my config file:

```
{
 "development": {
    "use_env_variable": "LOCALDB",
    "dialect": "mysql"
 },
 "test": {
    "username": "root",
    "password": null,
    "database": "database_test",
    "host": "127.0.0.1",
    "dialect": "mysql"
 },
 "production": {
    "use_env_variable": "JAWSDB_URL",
    "dialect": "mysql"
 }
}
```

Not entirely sure what I am doing wrong. :/

Comment: can you share your full `config` file?

Comment: updated post with full config file... @mcranston18

Answer (score 0):

You must export your configuration:

```
module.exports = {
 "development": {
    "use_env_variable": "LOCALDB",
    "dialect": "mysql"
 },
 "test": {
    "username": "root",
    "password": null,
    "database": "database_test",
    "host": "127.0.0.1",
    "dialect": "mysql"
 },
 "production": {
    "use_env_variable": "JAWSDB_URL",
    "dialect": "mysql"
 }
}
```

Comment: my mistake. On my projects, mine is an exported `.js` file, but I forgot config file can be JSON. Could you also post the file where you initialize Sequelize and pass in the DB config?